# CSS Diplay box and flex on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have a navbar in css that uses `display: flex;` and `display: box;` on parent and children (respectively).
The first html element uses `flex` where:

- `.menu-item` has 1 part
- `.submenu-item`s have 4 parts

The repartition is fixed.

Then the submenu use box and all are set to `box-flex: 1;` so that they can use the space they want.

The navbar renders corectly in Chrome, Safari and IE. But Firefox doesn't render it correctly.

How it's rendering in Chrome (and should in FF) :
[image]

How it's actually rendering in FF :
[image]

I have a [Dabblet exemple](http://dabblet.com/gist/9466127) of the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox needs `display:flex;` with eventually `justify-content:space-around;` for `.dropdon-menu`. It uses the new syntax . http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/
dabblet updated : http://dabblet.com/gist/9468022

EDIT.

`justify-content` doesn't feed your needs , so look at `flex` properties.

You can simply set `flex:1;` to `.submenu-item` :

some explanations here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Result :  http://dabblet.com/gist/9470629

Comment: Yeah this is almost this. But each link doesn't represent 100% and the hover effect looks realy bad. This is th only solution/hack possible ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the hover effect to take up more space? (i.e. so that each submenu-entry's hover-background covers exactly 1/4 of the space)  Then you just want "flex: 1" [or possibly "flex: 1 auto"] on each of the submenu-entries, instead of "justify-content: space-around".)

Comment: @dholbert , you are right , he should set :flex:1; to submenu-item;